# document.querySelectorAll together with div.style does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, styles

I'm again doing those random tests I sometimes do and just come up with the idea of creating following page:

- I've got `3` divs, all with a background color of `green` and a height of `50px`
- I've got `3` divs, all with a background color of `red` and a height of `100px`
- All those div´s act as if they were squares

Here's my code so far:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test StackOverflow</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="divgreen" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: green; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
  <div class="divgreen" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: green; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
  <div class="divgreen" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: green; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
  <div class="divred" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
  <div class="divred" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
  <div class="divred" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now I would like to set the height of all the green divs (while runtime, or, to be more specific, on page load) to the height of all the red divs. For that I chose to use JavaScript. After researching in the internet I managed to create the following script:

```js
function change() {
  var greens = document.querySelectorAll('.divgreen');
 var reds = document.querySelectorAll('.divred');
 for(var i=0; i<reds.length; i++) {
   greens[i].style.height = reds[i].style.height;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test StackOverflow</title>
 </head>
 <body onload="change();">
  <div class="divgreen" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: green; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
  <div class="divgreen" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: green; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
  <div class="divgreen" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: green; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
  <div class="divred" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
  <div class="divred" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
  <div class="divred" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 2px;"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

But that code seems not to work. What have I done wrong?

I've already logged everything in console with no results. I'd like to have it in JavaScript, but if you want to use jQuery, then, of course, you can.

In case you do use jQuery please explain to me the code as I can´t understand the short ways of jQuery quite as good as javascript.

By the way I´d be happy if you´d also show me in your answer how to set the width of the green divs to the height of the red divs.

Comment: Your snippet appears to work just fine.

Comment: As @Alohci said above - [it works](http://jsbin.com/jopirorope/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @Alohci Really? I´m using Firefox 51.0.1 and nothing seems to work fine at me...

Comment: @natanel97 I´m trying to get the height of the green div´s to the height of the red div´s...doesn´t seem to work....

Comment: *for(var i=0; i<reds.length&&i<greens.length; i++) {* <--- inportant! unless you want crashing sometimes...

Comment: @VicStudio The borders makes it 102px instead of 100, so you can use `box-sizing: border-box` to fix this

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, The borders makes the height `102px` instead of `100px` and that might be the problem. and this can be solved with a little use of CSS:

```
.divgreen, .divred {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Learn more about [`box-sizing` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) on mdn.

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem!